# Selecting multiple unique matches from one column that match another column

Tags: sql

I have a list of codes (101, 102, 103, 104) and I want to pick out the people in the following table that have two or more different codes from the list occurring within a year of each other.

```
    Name      Code1   Code1date  
    John      101     01/01/2016
    John      102     01/02/2013
    Chris     101     01/01/2015
    Chris     101     01/05/2014
    Chris     102     01/10/2015
    Mark      101     01/11/2011
    Mark      101     01/01/2011
    Mark      107     01/07/2012
```

So in this sample only Chris would be selected because he has a 101 code and a 102 code within a year of each other.

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, etc..

Comment: You will have to write a query for that. Write that query and post the results here.

Comment: You really need to specify dbms here. Too many have their own functionality for date/time, far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below query if you are using `SQL Server`.

```
SELECT name
FROM yourtable
WHERE code1 in (101, 102, 103, 104)
GROUP BY name, year(code1date)
HAVING COUNT(distinct code1) > 1
```

Comment: @matt fighting with negative votes ..:) any way i haven't given any down vote to any of the answer.. :P by the way, i have updated the filter condition as you mentioned.. Thanks for notifying.. :)

Comment: yep I removed the negative, though I caution OP that this is for when you want the user to have the code in the SAME Calendar year! not WITHIN 1 year.....Not fighting, just trying to balance the question to ensure a quality answer will be the most evident for future visitors of the question.  Good edit, plus got to say I have seen a few of your recent answers and appreciate your insight you have provided to others!

Answer (score 1):

### Version 1: Same year: happened in the same year

You need to make a group for each name and year and only show those distinct names that have more than 1 unique code:

```
select distinct name
from sample_table
where code1 between 101 and 104
group by name, extract(year from code1date)
having count(distinct code1) > 1
```

This will result in Chris only being presented in output.

`EXTRACT` function is ANSI-SQL compliant, but it will work assuming that `code1date` is of `date` type

In case it is of `text` data type, you could get 4 characters from the right, so for example `right(code1date, 4)`

### Version 2: Same year: scan back- and onwards for one year difference

If by one year you mean not the same year, but scanning backwards and onwards from a date for 1 year difference, then here's the solution for `Postgres`:

```
SELECT
  a.name
FROM sample_table a
JOIN sample_table b ON 
  a.name = b.name
  AND a.code1 <> b.code1
  AND b.code1date BETWEEN a.code1date - interval '1 year' AND a.code1date + interval '1 year'
WHERE a.code1 BETWEEN 101 AND 104
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.code1) > 1
```

Above also assumes that your `code1date` is of `date` type. If that's not the case then you should think about converting it to a proper format. If that's beyond your reach, then you could always get the last character from your column, cast to `Integer`, increment it and append it back to the substring without the last char thus replacing the value of year :-)

Comment: this doesn't account for them being within 1 year of eachoter

Comment: @Matt at first glance I didn't notice that - thanks.

Comment: no worries it happens.  I am wondering if within a year is meant to be in the same year as your answer suggests or within a year meaning 12/2015 is within 1 year of 2/2016.....

Comment: Ambiguities everywhere . . . :( Thank you SO for your minuses. It keeps me going!

Comment: yep by the way I am not the down vote, the OP may revise and this could be what he/she wants not sure yet

Comment: just missing the limiter on the list of desired codes, which will drop Mike off

Comment: Shooot ... you're right ^^ I'm sleeping probably. Thanks!

Comment: the last part is to limit the code list for both the where condition and the self join on condition

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    t1.Name
FROM
    TableName t1
    INNER JOIN TableName t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name
    AND t2.Code1Date BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,t1.Code1Date) AND DATEADD(year,1,t1.Code1Date)
    AND t1.Code1 <> t2.Code1
    AND t2.Code1 IN (101,102,103,104)
WHERE
    t1.Code1 IN (101,102,103,104)    
GROUP BY
    t1.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Code1) > 1
```

So this is for sql-server but just change up the BETWEEN statement to reflect the date functions of what ever rdbms you are working with.